# Ubuntu 21.10 bug on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberrypi, bug-reporting, 21.10

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10 from Ubuntu 21.04. I enjoy the new GNOME 40 desktop environment. Though, there is an issue with it. I am having issues with the Ubuntu Dock and the Applications Menu. Whenever I click on an app and try to drag the application from the dock or the menu, the desktop freezes or crashes. I have no choice, but to turn off the pi. I don't know why this happens. I own a raspberry pi 4 (8 gigabyte model).

I have tested this with the "Ubuntu on Xorg" environment, I clicked and dragged the application, but it lets me do it. There is no freeze / crash on the "Ubuntu on Xorg" but for Ubuntu on Wayland. This crashes.

Does anyone know about this? Is the Ubuntu Team going to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, bug reports are off-topic on Ask Ubuntu. _Does anybody know about it?_ Maybe. Maybe not. Someone will if you file a bug report, though. _Is the Ubuntu Team going to fix this?_ Maybe. Maybe not. Certainly not if nobody reports a bug. I suggest you read [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121/1438484).

Comment: Same deal on a raspberry pi 400. Sometimes REISUP works, sometimes not.

Comment: Cross-posted here https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/raspberry-pi-4-400-running-ubuntu-21-10-freezes-when-dragging-app-icon-to-dock/24696

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this too [on 20.10].

It appears to be a known bug, and the updated test kernel provided as a work-around solves the problem for me.

More information here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi/+bug/1946368

The link to the text kernel is contained in that thread... and their target is to get it in the mainline Ubuntu kernel by November 8th.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that even when the display is frozen (and cannot be resurrected), only the display driver appears to crash; the system remains operational (at least for some time) happily responding to SSH login requests or, if video is playing, continuing audio output.

So you can connect via SSH and logout, and login again

`gnome-session-quit --logout --force`

Or safely reboot without power unplugging:

`sudo reboot`

It`s actually what I am doing while waiting for patch release.